# jQuery UI Autocomplete does NOT filter items in the List

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I use jQuery UI Autocomplete to help user find a proper product.
Well, I have an html piece of code:

```
<input id="product_name" name="product" />
```

I pasted a JS code to fill the field:

```
$(document).on("focus", "#product_name", function() {

    $.get("index.php?route=order/form/getproducts", function(json) {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: json,
            minLength: 1
        });
    });

});
```

This JS code makes a request to the server where I have PHP+MySQL:

```
function getProducts() {

$results = $order_model->getProducts(false);
$product_names = array();

if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {         
        $product_names[] = $result["name"];
    }
    print_r(json_encode($product_names));
}
```

So what We get on output?
When User focus cursor on the field and start enter any letter System shows the product list BUT System shows all the items and even User will type any letters in the List does not change!
So how I should make jQuery UI filter the items?

upd. JSON response:
["item1","item2","item3"]

Comment: update question with your sample json response

Comment: Here is JsFiddle for client side autocomplete http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/532/  . For server side code, refer answer by "Ghost". It should  do the trick